# php fails to store any _SESSION or _GLOBALS variable

Tags: php

I am storing a session and a global variable in file1.php. However, when I try to access those from file2.php I get nothing. I am using php 5.1.6.

```
$_SESSION['abc'] = $a;
$GLOBALS['def'] = $b;
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have a code sample? I can oly guess you are missing a start session.

Comment: $GLOBALS won't store variables between pages. What are you trying to do?

Comment: indent your code lines 4 spaces to have it rendered as I edited it to, above.

Answer (score 2):

- Do you have cookies enabled on your browser?
- Are you remembering to call session_start at the top of BOTH pages?
- Are you storing your session variables in $_SESSION ? Nothing else will store.

In regards to your edit: The variable stored in $GLOBALS is just a global to that script. You have to put the value in $_SESSION to use across pages.

Example:

```
// Page 1
session_start();
$_SESSION['abc'] = "hello world";
$GLOBALS['def']  = "More stuff.";

// Page 2
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['abc'];   // prints 'hello world'
echo $GLOBALS['def'];   // is not defined. Globals aren't session variables.
```

Comment: Yes, I have cookies enabled on my host
I am calling session_start on both files right after <?php tags
I am using $_SESSION['abc'] = $a syntax to store session variables

When developing my app on my windows machine it works fine with php 5.3.0 but it fails on Linux running PHP 5.1.6

Comment: Going by your example above, are you sure that there's a value in $a? Try giving your session variable a string value like `$_SESSION['abc'] = 'hello'` to see if its your session failing, or something else.

Comment: Could it be any Apache/PHP config problem?

Comment: If it works locally for you, but not on your webhost, it may indeed be the way they have PHP set up, as sessions can be disabled. There's some information here: http://support.qualityunit.com/knowledgebase/general-questions/how-to-enable-session-support-for-php.html about enabling sessions via php.ini if you have the ability to use local .ini files.